# Определить наибольший элемент в каждой строке матрицы

Tags: матрицы, pascalabc.net

Долго проболел, не ходил в универ, задали:
Определить наибольший элемент в каждой строке матрицы A[B,C], где  B<=10, C<=15.

Можете объяснить, что тут вообще надо сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя есть матрица [10,15]:

1. Делаешь цикл по строкам.
2. Объявляешь переменную max = первому элементу в этой строке.
3. Бежишь по строке и сравниваешь max с текущим элементом x[i,j].
4. Если max < x[i,j] то max = x[i,j].
5. Выводишь max (или записываешь куда-нибудь).
6. Переходишь к следующей строке.

Comment: @whispeer Извините, а цикл по строкам это как.

Comment: @Vlmake 
т.е цикл который бежит по строкам матрицы (вот пример http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=520)

Answer (score 1):

Ну... Как что делать? Взять тетрадь у однокурсников и порешать задачи в ней, все.

А что непонятного? Наибольший элемент в наборе чисел (например, в массиве) определить умеете? Вот и прогоните определение наибольшего элемента для каждой из строк матрицы. (Как адресуются элементы в матрице, знаете?)

**Обновление**

Ну хоть с однокурсницами, девочки с первой парты обычно с удовольствием всё объясняют.

Насколько я понял задание, `B` и `C` — *размеры* матрицы, соответственно по иксу и по игреку. А числа в матрице любые.

**Обновление 2**

То есть вы

- заводите матрицу размера «с запасом»: 10 на 15;
- запрашиваете у юзера настоящие размеры. Проверяете, вылазят ли они за границы, если да, ругаетесь на юзера;
- вводите матрицу поэлементно; :(
- пробегаетесь по строкам, в каждой находите макс. элемент и выводите;
- PROFIT!